# Issue in extracting value from xml(apple rating xml) using BEAUTIFULSOUP python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text for

```
<im:rating>5</im:rating>
<im:version>1.14</im:version>
```

from xml of apple xml for app store review using BeautifulSoup.

my code is

```
def getReview():
    url = "https://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/page=1/id=511376996/sortby=mostrecent/xml?l=en&cc=us" 
        source = requests.get(url)
        text = source.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')
        for l in soup.findAll('entry'):
            rate=l.find('rating')
            author=(l.find('name')).text
            appver=l.find('version')

            print(rate)
            print(author)
            print(appver)
```

When I am using above code, I am getting text for author &

```
<im:rating>5</im:rating>
<im:version>1.14</im:version>
```

for rating & version and if i use             `appver=l.find('version').text` then it gives error

```
  appver=l.find('version').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I want to get only the value of these rating & version text.i.e for rating '5' & for version '1.14'.

Need help & thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure that you are actually getting the version? I'd assume based on the error that `appver` in your current code would be `None` to get the error you are getting.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen the app version is present in the page,when i am printing {appver=l.find('version')} it prints {<im:version>1.14</im:version>} but i want to get only 1.14 in place of {<im:version>1.14</im:version>}

Comment: just a note about formatting you can use the backtick (`) for code blocks, also when editing your question there is a ? button that gives further help for formatting.

Comment: Are you saying as posted your code errors?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham not the code block but when the line `appver=l.find('version')` is changed to `appver=l.find('version').text` it raises errors.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, OK, thanks

Comment: @GauravKumar, the simple answer is the first entry has no rating or version

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There are 50 entries on page & all entries have rating & version number associated, i want to learn a way to extract there value inplace of complete html tag

Comment: @GauravKumar, no, read the xml, in particular the first *entry*,  use `soup.select("entry + entry")` and you wills see your code runs fine calling  .text

Comment: @GauravKumar it does if you skip the first entry, you cannot scrape something that does not exist

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get those tags, a simple pyparsing parser will get them without the BeautifulSoup hoops to jump through. By just parsing for the given tags (pyparsing's tag matching is pretty comprehensive), you can skip the overhead of parsing the entire HTML and just getting at the pieces that you want, and get them back in a simplified structure of your own design. See below, with comments, and a simulated HTML with 3 entries:

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, SkipTo, ungroup

def get_tag_body(start_tag, end_tag):
    return ungroup(start_tag.suppress() + SkipTo(end_tag) + end_tag.suppress())

# makeHTMLTags returns a 2-tuple containing expressions for the
# corresponding start tag and end tag

rating_expr = get_tag_body(*makeHTMLTags("im:rating"))("rating")
version_expr = get_tag_body(*makeHTMLTags("im:version"))("version")

# the desired pattern is the rating_expr followed by the version_expr
search_parser = rating_expr + version_expr

# parse the posted sample
sample = """
<im:rating>5</im:rating>
<im:version>1.14</im:version> 
"""

# access the named fields using dot notation or dict key notation
results = search_parser.searchString(sample)
if results:
    for res in results:
        print("rating = {rating}, version = {version}".format_map(res))
```

prints:

```
rating = 5, version = 1.14
```

Comment: This does not look easier, it raises an error with the data being used in the OP, and it doesn't actually answer the question asked about the error, and I do not understand the output at all.

Comment: I took out the distracting bits, and just put in the posted sample, which does not raise an error for me, as shown by the posted output.

Comment: I meant the link: https://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/page=1/id=511376996/sortby=mostrecent/xml?l=en&cc=us is the exact data that the OP is trying to parse, I'm still don't see how this is any better then BeautifulSoup, it certainly is takes longer to execute.

Comment: I'm still not getting an error, even when using the XML fetched from the URL in the OP, and I *do* find 50 rating-version pairs. What error did you get? As for whether this is better than BeautifulSoup or not, the OP can choose - SO has many constructive answers that propose alternative approaches or libraries to solve a posted problem. (Just look at all the questions on how to parse HTML using regex, with Beautiful Soup offered as an alternative approach.)